# How to add configuration for MongoDB 4.2 Transaction in spring boot?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I added the code for the the transactions in my project, but it returns below error.

Error: sessions are not supported by the mongodb cluster to which this client is connected

I did some research and I found that we cannot implement mongo db transactions in standlone, is there a way we can do in standalone server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replica set is the resolution for the issue for sure

As per various documents online **doing replica of 3 nodes is not mandatory**.

**Solution 1** (for standalone setup)

For standalone mongo installation you can skip configuring 2nd or 3rd node as described on the official mongo documentations [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-for-testing/)

And you'll need to set a [replSetName](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/index.html#replication.replSetName) in the configuration

```
replication:
   oplogSizeMB: <int>
   replSetName: <string>
   enableMajorityReadConcern: <boolean>
```

and then run details of which are [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.initiate/index.html#rs-initiate)

```
rs.initiate()
```

after this the connection string would be like below:-

```
mongodb://localhost:27017/<database_name>?replicaSet=<replSet_Name>
```

keys above that you need to replace:-

**database_name** = name of the database

**replSet_Name** = name of the replica set you setup in the above configuration

---

**Solution 2** (only for docker based requirement)

Example Docker image with **single node replica set acting as primary node** for development environment is as below:-

I had hosted the **docker image on the docker hub**

```
docker pull krnbr/mongo:latest
```

Contents of the same **Dockerfile** are below:-

```
FROM mongo
RUN echo "rs.initiate({'_id':'rs0','members':[{'_id':0,'host':'127.0.0.1:27017'}]});" > /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/replica-init.js
RUN cat /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/replica-init.js
CMD [ "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "rs0" ]
```

Docker run command (replace  with the image name that you build yoursef or use the on shared above i.e **krnbr/mongo**):-

**without volume**

```
docker run -d --name mongo -p 27017:27017 <Image Name> mongod --replSet rs0 --port 27017
```

**with volume**

```
docker run -d --name mongo -p 27017:27017 -v ~/.mongodb:/data/db <Image Name> mongod --replSet rs0 --port 27017
```

for supporting **binding of any ip**

```
docker run -d --name mongo -p 27017:27017 -v ~/.mongodb:/data/db <Image Name> mongod --bind_ip_all --replSet rs0 --port 27017
```

Answer (score 0):

Transactions in MongoDB require [read concern majority](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-concern-majority/index.html) which depends on replication.

You can't get that on a strictly "standalone" node, but you can create a replica set with only one member.

To do that you'll need to specify a [replSetName](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/index.html#replication.replSetName) in the configuration, and run [rs.initiate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.initiate/index.html#rs-initiate)